# Add number to each number in string (python)

Tags: python

is there any way to run this specific code in python:

```
str = input() # multiline input, keep each line
for x in str: if x is number: replace x with x+3: print multiline new str
```

Thanks!

Comment: can you please add some more details about the object of the code.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.com! Please provide us with any code you have so far, example input, desired output and the (wrong) output you're getting. The way you're question currently phrased, there is serious mismatch between the title and the body. And it is not clear what exactly `is a number` means to you.

Comment: [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) reads a single line.

Comment: does `for x in str` mean for each character or each line?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there's a single number on each line, this should do the trick:

```
s = read_input()
new_s = []
for line in s.splitlines():
    try:
        x = int(line)
        x += 3
        x = str(x)
    except ValueError:
        x = line
    new_s.append(x)
new_s = '\n'.join(new_s)  # join the new lines
print(new_s)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple numbers per line (assuming you treat each individual digit as its own number):

```
print [int(x)+3 for x in str if x.isdigit()]
```

Results:

```
str='adf3serf9dff7'
print [int(x)+3 for x in str if x.isdigit()]
>>>[6, 12, 10]
```